# Need Regular Expression to get Anchor id

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have below anchor tag in my code and i need to get anchor id using regular expression.

```
<a id="_ghidd" class="bh">TestLink </a>
```

TestLink

if i give anchor tag t regular expression i need to get output as "-ghidd".

Please help me with above issue.

Thanks
Srini

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for serious html parsing then use a serious html parser (like html agility pack)

However, if you are just looking for a once-off novel Regex pattern, the following will work

```
(?<=id=").*?(?=")
```

[**Demo here**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3Did%3D%22%29.*%3F%28%3F%3D%22%29&i=%3Ca%20id%3D%22_ghidd%22%20class%3D%22bh%22%3ETestLink%20%3C%2Fa%3E)

**Disclaimer**, i am not responsible for anyone you maim or injure with this code

Comment: need regex only as i am using it in RPA openspan